# How to subset dataframe based on a "not equal to" criteria applied to a large number of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I'm new to R and currently trying to subset my data according to my predefined exclusion criteria for analysis. I'm presently trying to remove all cases that have dementia, as coded by the ICD-10. Problem is that there are multiple variables containing information on each individual's disease status (~70 variables), although as they are coded in the same way, the same condition can be applied to all of them.

Some simulated data:

```
#Create dataframe containing simulated data
df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011),
                    disease_code_1 = c('I802','H356','G560','D235','B178','F011','F023','C761','H653','A049','J679'),
                    disease_code_2 = c('A071','NA','G20','NA','NA','A049','NA','NA','G300','G308','A045'),
                    disease_code_3 = c('H250','NA','NA','I802','NA','A481','NA','NA','NA','NA','D352'))

#data is structured as below:

     ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
1  1001           I802           A071           H250
2  1002           H356             NA             NA
3  1003           G560            G20             NA
4  1004           D235             NA           I802
5  1005           B178             NA             NA
6  1006           F011           A049           A481
7  1007           F023             NA             NA
8  1008           C761             NA             NA
9  1009           H653           G300             NA
10 1010           A049           G308             NA
11 1011           J679           A045           D352
```

Here, I'm trying to remove any case that has a 'dementia code' across any of the "disease_code" variables.

```
#Remove cases with dementia from dataframe (e.g. F023, G20)
Newdata_df <- subset(df, (2:4 != "F023"|"G20"|"F009"|"F002"|"F001"|"F000"|"F00"|    
                    "G309"| "G308"|"G301"|"G300"|"G30"| "F01"|"F018"|"F013"|
                    "F012"| "F011"| "F010"|"F01"))
```

The error that I recieve is:

```
Error in 2:4 != "F023" | "G20" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Ideally, the subsetted dataframe would look like this:

```
     ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
1  1001           I802           A071           H250
2  1002           H356             NA             NA
4  1004           D235             NA           I802
5  1005           B178             NA             NA
8  1008           C761             NA             NA
11 1011           J679           A045           D352
```

I know that there is an error in my code although I'm not sure how exactly to fix it. I've tried a few other ways (using dplyr) although haven't had any luck so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should reshape your data to long format. That will make your life (and analysis) much easier.

Comment: And keep the CRAN package [icd](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/icd/index.html) in mind to retain your sanity. Many problems similar to this benefit from or require applying comorbidity maps, which `icd` does very carefully and quickly using well validated, widely-cited disease maps. This doesn't answer your question, but using this technique might have avoided this problem, depending on what you had already done, and what you were going to do with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 filter_at(vars(2:4), all_vars(! . %in% c("F023","G20","F009","F002","F001","F000","F00",    
            "G309", "G308","G301","G300","G30", "F01","F018","F013",
            "F012", "F011", "F010","F01")))

    ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
1 1001           I802           A071           H250
2 1002           H356             NA             NA
3 1004           D235             NA           I802
4 1005           B178             NA             NA
5 1008           C761             NA             NA
6 1011           J679           A045           D352
```

In this case, it checks whether any of the columns 2:4 contains any of the given codes.

Or:

```
df %>%
 filter_at(vars(contains("disease_code")), all_vars(! . %in% c("F023","G20","F009","F002","F001","F000","F00",    
            "G309", "G308","G301","G300","G30", "F01","F018","F013",
            "F012", "F011", "F010","F01")))
```

In this case, it checks whether any of the columns with names `disease_code` contains any of the given codes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions! I appreciate that you also explained what your suggested code does @tmfmnk  - really useful!

Answer (score 4):

We can create a vector with the codes to be removed and use `rowSums` to remove, i.e.

```
codes_to_remove <- c("F023", "G20", "F009", "F002", "F001", "F000", "F00", "G309", "G308",
                "G301", "G300", "G30", "F01", "F018", "F013", "F012", "F011", "F010", "F01")

df[rowSums(sapply(df[-1], `%in%`, codes_to_remove)) == 0,]
```

which gives,

> ```
>      ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
> 1  1001           I802           A071           H250
> 2  1002           H356             NA             NA
> 4  1004           D235             NA           I802
> 5  1005           B178             NA             NA
> 8  1008           C761             NA             NA
> 11 1011           J679           A045           D352
> ```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
> dementia <- c("F023", "G20", "F009", "F002", "F001", "F000", "F00", "G309", "G308",
+               "G301", "G300", "G30", "F01", "F018", "F013", "F012", "F011", "F010", "F01")
> 
> dementia <- apply(sapply(df[, -1], function(x) {x %in% dementia}), 1, any)
> 
> df[!dementia,]
     ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
1  1001           I802           A071           H250
2  1002           H356             NA             NA
4  1004           D235             NA           I802
5  1005           B178             NA             NA
8  1008           C761             NA             NA
11 1011           J679           A045           D352
>
```

**Edit:**

An even more elegant solution, thanks to @ Ronan Shah:

```
> df[apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {!any(x %in% dementia)}),]
     ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
1  1001           I802           A071           H250
2  1002           H356             NA             NA
4  1004           D235             NA           I802
5  1005           B178             NA             NA
8  1008           C761             NA             NA
11 1011           J679           A045           D352
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Ronan Shah Nice! Its a more elegant solution. You should post it.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments by @docendo discimus we can convert the dataframe to long format using `gather`, `group_by` `ID` and select only those `ID`s which do not have `dementia_code` in them and then `spread` them back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(!any(value %in% dementia_code)) %>%
   spread(key, value)

#   ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
#  <dbl> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
#1  1001 I802           A071           H250          
#2  1002 H356           NA             NA            
#3  1004 D235           NA             I802          
#4  1005 B178           NA             NA            
#5  1008 C761           NA             NA            
#6  1011 J679           A045           D352
```

**data**

```
dementia_code <- c("F023", "G20", "F009", "F002", "F001", "F000", "F00", "G309", 
"G308","G301", "G300", "G30", "F01", "F018", "F013", "F012", "F011", "F010", "F01")
```

Comment: Why load all of `tidyverse`? Isn't this just `tidyr` and `dplyr`?

Comment: @Dunois yes, it is. I have a habit of loading it all up by default :P

Comment: We could also do it using an `anti_join` such as `Newdata_df <- 
  df %>% 
  anti_join(df %>% 
              gather(DiseaseCodeNumber, CodeValue, -ID) %>% 
              filter(CodeValue %in% c("F023","G20","F009","F002","F001","F000","F00",    
                                      "G309", "G308","G301","G300","G30","F01","F018","F013",
                                      "F012", "F011","F010","F01")), by = "ID")`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = 'ID')[,
     if(!any(value %in% dementia_codes)) .SD, .(ID)], ID ~ variable)
#    ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
#1: 1001           I802           A071           H250
#2: 1002           H356             NA             NA
#3: 1004           D235             NA           I802
#4: 1005           B178             NA             NA
#5: 1008           C761             NA             NA
#6: 1011           J679           A045           D352
```

---

Or this can be done more compactly in `base R` with no reshaping

```
df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], `%in%` , dementia_codes)),]
 #   ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
#1  1001           I802           A071           H250
#2  1002           H356             NA             NA
#4  1004           D235             NA           I802
#5  1005           B178             NA             NA
#8  1008           C761             NA             NA
#11 1011           J679           A045           D352
```

#### data

```
dementia_codes <- c("F023", "G20", "F009", "F002", "F001", "F000", 
  "F00", "G309", "G308", "G301", "G300", "G30", "F01", "F018", "F013", 
   "F012", "F011", "F010", "F01")
```

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop version with `base` R, in case you prefer that.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011),
                disease_code_1 = c('I802','H356','G560','D235','B178','F011','F023','C761','H653','A049','J679'),
                disease_code_2 = c('A071','NA','G20','NA','NA','A049','NA','NA','G300','G308','A045'),
                disease_code_3 = c('H250','NA','NA','I802','NA','A481','NA','NA','NA','NA','D352'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dementia_codes <- c("F023", "G20", "F009", "F002", "F001", "F000", "F00", "G309", "G308", "G301", "G300", "G30", "F01", "F018", "F013", "F012", "F011", "F010", "F01")

new_df <- df[0,]

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  currRow <- df[i,]
  if(any(dementia_codes %in% as.character(currRow)) == FALSE){
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, currRow)
  }
}

new_df
#      ID disease_code_1 disease_code_2 disease_code_3
# 1  1001           I802           A071           H250
# 2  1002           H356             NA             NA
# 4  1004           D235             NA           I802
# 5  1005           B178             NA             NA
# 8  1008           C761             NA             NA
# 11 1011           J679           A045           D352
```